# the_post_thumbnail() get the URL to the "medium" sized image

Tags: theme-development, post-thumbnails

In the script below, I need to get the URL path to the "medium" size image in the "data-responsive" attribute. Its currently returning the thumbnail size.

```
the_post_thumbnail("thumbnail", 
    array(
        'itemprop' => 'image',
        'class' => 'alignleft', 
        'style' => 'margin:5px 15px 10px 0;', 
        'data-responsive' => wp_get_attachment_thumb_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'medium')
        )
    );
```

I want the thumbnail used as the default image, however, I need to write the URL to the medium sized image so that I can use that in media queries to swap the image to higher res on larger devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wp_get_attachment_thumb_url()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_attachment_thumb_url/) does not accept size as argument.

You might be looking for [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_attachment_image_src/), but I am not sure on top of my head - too many functions in that corner.